# Where is Applicant Response to Pre-Exam Formalities Notice on EFS Web?

Tags: applicant-response

I have been asked to update some drawings for an application I submitted online, and told I could submit my reply via EFS-Web. However, after authentication, I am told that I am not authorized to access the application & confirmation numbers which I was sent by the USPTO.

I cannot find any other way to submit the drawings online. Where should I look?

Comment: If they told you you could submit that way maybe you should call them and ask what went wrong. Somebody here might know, but I think calling would be the fastest solution.

Comment: The customer service at USPTO is excellent in my experience.  Definitely give them a call.

Comment: So you have a customer number and a PKI key for EFS Web and Private PAIR?

Answer (score -1):

In EFS Web look under the Pre-exam category and choose "Applicant Response to Pre-Exam Formalities Notice".